# ContentTypesFilter, проблемы aiogram'а

Tags: python, aiogram

писал бота на python aiogram, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: нужно было скачать картинку которую кидают боту - для определения сообщения с картинкой я попытался импортировать класс ContentTypesFilter из модуля aiogram.filters. но вот петля - такого класса нету. попытался почитать документацию - утонул в воде. вопрос: чем он заменен в новых версиях?

Answer (score 0):

я сам изучаю этот фреймворк, и как я понял он заменен на F.photo который импотируется из aiogram с остальными F

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
```

Answer (score 0):

Он заменен на [магический фильтр](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html):

В вашем случае, что бы хендлер срабатывал только на фото нужно написать примерно так:

```
from aiogram import F


@router.message(F.photo)
async def any_digits_handler(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Это фото")
```